# Using shared_ptr with FreeRTOS queue

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, freertos

I use ESP-32 and need to pass `std::shared_ptr` using FreeRTOS queue. However, it loose one link. I think that this is source of a problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#define PRINT_USE_COUNT(p) std::cout << "Use count: " << p.use_count() << std::endl;

extern "C" {
    #include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
    #include <freertos/task.h>
    #include <freertos/queue.h>
}

class testClass {
    public:
        testClass() {
            std::cout << "Class is constructed" << std::endl;
        };
        virtual ~testClass() {
            std::cout << "Class is destructed" << std::endl;
        };
};

struct container {
    std::shared_ptr<testClass> field;
};

extern "C" void app_main(void) {
    auto queue = xQueueCreate(1, sizeof(container));
    auto p = std::make_shared<testClass>();
    PRINT_USE_COUNT(p); // 1
    {
        container c;
        c.field = p;
        PRINT_USE_COUNT(p); // 2
        xQueueSendToBack(queue, &c, 0);
        PRINT_USE_COUNT(p); // 2
    }
    PRINT_USE_COUNT(p); // 1 (Ooops!)
    {
        container c;
        assert(xQueueReceive(queue, &c, 0) == pdTRUE);
        PRINT_USE_COUNT(c.field); // 1
    }
    // Class is destructed
    std::cout << "Test finished" << std::endl;
    vQueueDelete(queue);
}
```

So there is a pointer in queue, but it isn't counted!

How can I solve this issue (and keep using FreeRTOS queue if possible)? Using `std::move` doesn't help.

Comment: How do you allocate `sound` ? It's hard to tell what you're doing without a minimal example of SoundControl implementation and without knowing how you declare and allocate sound

Comment: @Clonk Is there enought details for now?

Comment: Try to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Remove unnecessary attribute member to struct. It's really important to show HOW you allocate your object and store it and how you move reference around.

Comment: @Clonk I made complete example. Can you check it now?

Comment: I'll take a look ! Thanks for your effort in making a quality question :)

Comment: FreeRTOS `queue` is a `C` (con)struct. I highly doubt it was designed with C++ classes in mind and as such it probably can't handle anything but PODs/trivial classes. I.e. no destructors and such. Looking at the documentation, it just accepts plain `void *` and copies it to its storage byte-by-byte. You won't be able to fix it unless they provide C++ API or at least a way to pass deleter.

Comment: My best guess is, that RTOS needs a raw pointer and you pass it, but then the destructor of shared_ptr will clean up the pointer regardless of the passed raw pointer. You have to that manually I'm afraid.

Comment: FREERTOS queue functions use plain memcpy to add items to queue, just look at source code. Queue is created with sizeof(item) parameter, and then it just copies n bytes to/from the queue. Plain C.

Comment: When you feed the queue with your `container` object, I suspect it just does a `memcpy`, assuming the object is a POD of size `sizeof (container)`. This doesn't do well at all with object oriented design and RAII

Comment: Thank you for all your comments! It proves my suggestions, but is there any solution to that?

Comment: Use a C++ friendly serialization framework?

Comment: Pass plain pointers and manage object lifetime yourself, don't expect this from  FREERTOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C-style queue of raw pointers will only works for C++ shared_ptr iff `std::is_trivial<T>::value` is true (mainly POD or trivially copyable object).

Since there are memcpy and other plain C operation manipulating memory the reference count will not be handled properly (because it is C-code behind the scene and it does not call destructor among other thing) and you could end up with a memory leak.

There is no easy way to circumvent this, but the best way is to manage the memory yourself.

See this question also : [Shared pointers and queues in FreeRTOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513057/shared-pointers-and-queues-in-freertos)

Comment: Thank you. I probably have to write C++ FreeRTOS queue from scratch.

Comment: I know that there are C++ wrapper on git hub for freeRTOS, maybe someone already developed something similar. But usually the best solution is to develop something suited to your need.

Comment: After thinking a lot, I'm using C++ queue with mutex (it is enought in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to transform unique pointer into a raw format which could be sent via a message queue.
See here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/241886/using-unique-ptr-in-freertos.

Please note I posted it in code review because I am not sure whether there are really no memory leaks or this can be implemented much more cleanly.
I will test whether I can actually use this for the IPC in our project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't always agree that developing something from scratch is best option. Using something that is well tested might be best option in most occasions even-though it could require some tweaking for making it fit to your needs.

With the queue you can pass a dynamically created instance of your container. It is very rare, if it is at all, to use a queue for sending data from one task to same task, as the example above. I don't like pretty much working with dynamic allocations in embedded CPUs, the overhead can sometimes impact performance too much.

Here below is a working PoC where, instead of a raw copy, a pointer to a new container instance is passed. In this approach it is the responsibility of the receiving task to release the instance to avoid memory leaks.

```
extern "C" {
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/queue.h"
}

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#define PRINT_USE_COUNT(p) std::cout << "Use count: " << p.use_count() << std::endl;

class testClass {
public:
    testClass() {
        std::cout << "testClass constructed" << std::endl;
    }

    ~testClass() {
        std::cout << "testClass destructed" << std::endl;
    }
};

class myContainer {
public:
    myContainer(std::shared_ptr<testClass> p) {
        _p = p;
        std::cout << "myContainer constructed" << std::endl;
    }

    ~myContainer() {
        std::cout << "myContainer destructed" << std::endl;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<testClass>& p() {
        return _p;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<testClass> _p;
};

extern "C" void app_main(void) {
    std::cout << "Start of test, creating the shared_ptr..." << std::endl;
    auto p = std::make_shared<testClass>();
    PRINT_USE_COUNT(p);

    std::cout << "Creating one container..." << std::endl;
    myContainer c(p);
    PRINT_USE_COUNT(p);

    std::cout << "Creating the queue..." << std::endl;
    auto q = xQueueCreate(1, sizeof(myContainer*));

    std::cout << "Sending a dynamically created item to the queue..."
            << std::endl;
    myContainer *cp = new myContainer(p);
    xQueueSendToBack(q, &cp, 0);
    PRINT_USE_COUNT(p);

    {
        myContainer *pc;

        xQueueReceive(q, &pc, 0);
        PRINT_USE_COUNT(p);
        std::cout << "Use count of pc->p() " << pc->p().use_count()
                << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Freeing the dynamically created item..." << std::endl;
        delete pc;
        PRINT_USE_COUNT(p);
    }

    std::cout << "end of test" << std::endl;
}
```

Here's the program's output:

> Start of test, creating the shared_ptr...
>
> testClass constructed
>
> Use count: 1
>
> Creating one container...
>
> myContainer constructed
>
> Use count: 2
>
> Creating the queue...
>
> Sending a dynamically created item to the queue...
>
> myContainer constructed
>
> Use count: 3
>
> Use count: 3
>
> Use count of pc->p() 3
>
> Freeing the dynamically created item...
>
> myContainer destructed
>
> Use count: 2
>
> end of test
>
> myContainer destructed
>
> testClass destructed

Comment: I don't know what could be the advantage of creating another container wrapping container. Maybe it could be better to send a dynamically created shared_ptr.